# Strftime Displays Different Abbreviation for a Time Zone in Different Machines/Servers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unix, timezone

I was debugging a display problem in our Rails application, which takes an input of user time zone and a scheduled time and format it as a string of user readable schedule time. In this case, the user timezone is Ekaterinburg, and the weird part is that the time abbreviation displayed is different between the AWS server with Ubuntu 16.04 and my Macbook with Yosemite. The ruby versions are both the same (2.2.6p396) and both are the same Rails application(with same Gemfile and Gemfile.lock). This is the line I use to parse the time zone and time:

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new("Ekaterinburg").parse("11:29 am").strftime("%l:%M%p %Z")
```

The formatted time displayed in the server is

> "11:29AM +05"

While the formatted time displayed in my local machine is

> "11:29AM YEKT"

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Your local machine is behind on tzdata updates.  See dup answer, along with [this commit](https://github.com/eggert/tz/commit/1ac038c2c3f25f7211474ae08feb6afb820e35fe) and [this announcement](http://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz-announce/2016-September/000041.html) from the tzdb.

Comment: Thanks! tzdata is definitely new to me.

Answer (score 1):

As per [the documentation on `strftime`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Time.html#method-i-strftime):

> `%z` - Time zone as hour and minute offset from UTC (e.g. +0900)
>
> `%Z` - Abbreviated time zone name or similar information.  (OS dependent)

If you want it consistent, use `%z`.